# power bi lookup and match value from another table

Tags: powerbi

how to create a DAX formula to return the 'Progress' value in Table A from Table B matching the Table A [Order Status] to Table B [Status]

Do I need to set relationship between Table A [Order Status] and Table B [Status].  I tried to set relationship Table B to Table A One to many(1:*) but got error saying the cardinality selected isn't valid.  please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as you describe, with a relationship between `'Table A'[Order Status]` and `'Table B'[Status]`.

But if you want to make a measure you can use `USERELATIONSHIP` as part of `CALCULATE`, for example:

```
Progress Measure =
CALCULATE(
    MAX( 'Table B'[Progress] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(
        'Table A'[Order Status]
        'Table B'[Status]
    )
)
```

Alternatively you can make the join in Power Query.